# Collection was modified regardless its lock protection

Tags: asynchronous, collections, locking, task, .net-core

I am aware of collection was modified exception problem, but I can't see it in this instance. I know how to fix it, I just want to understand why it occurs here.

So, I've got a set of TaskCompletionSources and I've got a lockObject that protects access to that set. In one task (T1), I want to create TCS and wait up to 3 seconds for the task to be completed.

In the other task (T2), I want to wait half a second and then complete the task T1 is waiting for.

The set of TCSs is not exactly of any use in this code snippet, but in the actual program I'm working on, this is to hold the list of certain number of different waiters that should all be notified once the task is complete and this should also clear the list of waiters. In this snippet we only have one waiter (T1), but the set of TCSs has to be used to reproduce the problem.

The program produces the following output:

```
T1 start.
Wait start.
Add start.
Add end.
T2 start.
CompleteAndClear start.
Completing 1 TCSs.
Remove start.
Remove end.
Wait end.
Wait succeeded.
T1 end.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.CompleteAndClear() in Program.cs:line 104
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.<T2Async>d__5.MoveNext() in Program.cs:line 45
...
```

What I don't understand:

- Why the exception is thrown?
- How is that the Remove method can start and finish while CompleteAndClear is still holding the lock?

To me, it seems like TrySetResult causes the Wait to be finished using the same thread that holds the lock - so the current thread jumps to the WaitAsync function, goes to Remove, lock is then bypassed by the fact that this thread does hold the lock from CompleteAndClear (locks are reentrant by the same thread) and then since the Remove changed the HashSet, the exception is called. But the intention was that the thread executing CompleteAndClear will just mark the tasks as complete by setting their results, then it clears the set and releases the lock and only then Remove can enter the lock, and it should report "TCS not found.".

The trivial fix in the code is to replace

```
      Remove(tcs);
```

with

```
      if (!res) Remove(tcs);
```

which works perfectly, but does not go along with the intention. Another one is to make a copy of the set before clearing it and set results on the copy, which solves the case completely.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static object lockObject = new object();

    static HashSet<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> completionSources = new HashSet<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
      Task t1 = T1Async();
      Task t2 = T2Async();
      await t1;
      await t2;
    }

    static async Task T1Async()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("T1 start.");

      if (await WaitAsync()) Console.WriteLine("Wait succeeded.");
      else Console.WriteLine("Wait failed.");

      Console.WriteLine("T1 end.");
    }

    static async Task T2Async()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("T2 start.");

      await Task.Delay(500);
      CompleteAndClear();

      Console.WriteLine("T2 end.");
    }


    static async Task<bool> WaitAsync()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Wait start.");
      bool res = false;
      TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
      using (CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(3000))
      {
        using (CancellationTokenRegistration cancellationTokenRegistration = cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => { tcs.TrySetResult(false); }))
        {
          Add(tcs);

          res = await tcs.Task;

          Remove(tcs);
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Wait end.");
      return res;
    }

    static void Add(TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletionSource)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Add start.");

      lock (lockObject)
      {
        completionSources.Add(TaskCompletionSource);
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Add end.");
    }

    static void Remove(TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletionSource)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Remove start.");

      lock (lockObject)
      {
        if (!completionSources.Remove(TaskCompletionSource)) Console.WriteLine("TCS not found.");
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Remove end.");
    }


    static void CompleteAndClear()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("CompleteAndClear start.");
      lock (lockObject)
      {
        if (completionSources.Count > 0)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Completing {0} TCSs.", completionSources.Count);
          foreach (TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs in completionSources)
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);

          Console.WriteLine("Clearing TCS list.");
          completionSources.Clear();
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("CompleteAndClear end.");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your problem is that `TaskCompletionSource<T>.TrySetResult` will *synchronously* invoke any task continuations that were registered with `TaskContinuationOption.ExecuteSynchronously`, combined with the fact that [`await` does use that flag](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html).

So, `CompleteAndClear` will take the lock and then call `TrySetResult` *while holding that lock*. [Since this is in a free-threaded context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/07/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/), `TrySetResult` will *synchronously* resume the `WaitAsync` method, which then calls `Remove`, which takes the lock (succeeding because `lock` permits recursive locks) and modifies the collection. When `TrySetResult` returns (after the `Remove` is done), the enumerator will then detect the problem and throw the exception.

There are a few (IMO questionable) design decisions that are working together here. I object to [`await` using `ExecuteSynchronously`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) as well as [recursive locks in general](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) (the section "Inconsistent Invariants" particularly applies to this scenario).

However, you can still avoid the problems inherent in these design decisions by stringently following one of the [key principles of multithreading: never invoke arbitrary code while holding a lock](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/avoid-calling-unknown-code-while-inside/202802983). Of course, what's not at all obvious is that `TaskCompletionSource<T>.TrySetResult` *can* invoke arbitrary code.

Now, on to solutions.

If you are targeting a new enough runtime (I believe `netstandard1.3`/`.NET Core 1.0` and higher), then you can pass `Task​Creation​Options.​Run​Continuations​Asynchronously` into the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` constructor. This gives you the most desirable behavior: the task is completed immediately and synchronously, but all continuations are forced to be asynchronous.

For older platforms, you can encapsulate the "completion" work (that is, the invocation of `TrySetResult`) within a delegate (I recommend further wrapping in an `IDisposable`), and delay that work until after the method has released its lock.

Finally, I recommend first writing async-compatible coordination primitives, and then using these to build more complex structures such as queues of work. It's much easier to deal with these tricky situations in just part of your code, or possibly even outsource it. E.g., my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) has a full suite of async-compatible coordination primitives; [v5 uses the new `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/eeff91de895f68c8217b3ceaad05f2f8ec66c062/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskCompletionSourceExtensions.cs#L82) flag, while [v4 uses the delay-completion-with-`IDisposable` workaround](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/v4/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/AsyncLock.cs#L141).

Comment: Thanks for lovely explanation. You got me on "`TrySetResult` can invoke arbitrary code." - I did not know this. Its docu is too short for my taste. If I understand what you are saying here, the default behavior of `await` is `ExecuteSynchronously` and you can override that if you use `TaskCreationOptions` when creating TCS. Is that right? If it is right, however, in the articles you have linked, you mention that sometimes these options are not respected (but those seem to be edge cases), so can we rely here on using `​Run​Continuations​Asynchronously` to never run in sync mode?

Comment: Two more questions if I may: You wrote that recursive locks were bad, so do you recommend in general to avoid using `lock()` construct? If so, what do you recommend to use instead? And the second is - if I am not missing something, just using non-recursive locking mechanism here would not help me at all, or?

Comment: I mean my first question in second comment here really is - if I use my `lock()`s non-recursively (by design of my code), is it still better to avoid them and use different constructs?

Comment: Yes, `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` overrides `ExecuteSynchronously` and you can depend on it to *always* run the continuations asynchronously. I do recommend using `lock`, but just write code that doesn't depend on its recursive nature. If `lock` was not recursive, it wouldn't fix this code, but it would reliably cause a deadlock instead of corrupting state.